# How to allow allow unrestricted local machine communication in Win2k8 for IPSec Local Security Policy?

Tags: windows, ipsec

I need to block all IP on a network and give unrestricted access to 3-4 computers.

So I have created IP Sec policy as follows:
**IP List 1**: added  to 4 IPs and associated a filter to **Permit**
**IP List 2**: added  to Any IP Address and associated a filter to **Block**

After adding this policy, application (using socket communication for IPC in local machine) is **working fine in Win7 machine**. But not in **Win2k8 machine**.

Please note for inpterprocess communication within a machine we use sockets.

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we enable block filter for all IPs in IPSec pollicy, the if there are programs which uses local machine IP itself like 10.78.78.78 connects to 10.78.78.78 (Both server and client application in same machine) for Inter process communication, then had to add a firewall exception for exempting authentication between the same machine IPs.